# fcitx shows input method change popup, but does not change keyboard layout

Tags: release-juno, keyboard, keyboard-layout, fcitx

I need 2 input languages on my `elementary OS 5.0 Juno`: English and Russian and I want to have different input methods in different windows. I was trying to use `ibus`, but it caused lags, so I have decided to switch to `fcitx`. And I still unsuccessful with trying to configure it.

Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> does trigger the popup which shows that my language is Russian. Status panel shows me Russian too (for some reason I don't have tray icon, but it's fine for the moment).

Actions which was done by me in order:

1. Download `fcitx` using `apt install`
2. Put following lines in my `/etc/profile.d/input-method-config.sh`:

   ```
   export XMODIFIERS="@im=fcitx"
   export GTK_IM_MODULE="fcitx"
   export QT_IM_MODULE="fcitx"
   export QT4_IM_MODULE="fcitx"
   export CLUTTER_IM_MODULE="fcitx"
   ```
3. Change input method in `im-config` to `fcitx`
4. Delete `ibus`

`fcitx-diagnose` shows me several issues, which does not seem crucial for me, but I don't know how to fix them anyway:

```
Config GUI for gtk2:

    **Config GUI for gtk2 not found.**
Config GUI for kde:

    **`kcmshell4` not found.**
gtk 2:

    **Cannot find `gtk-query-immodules` for gtk 2**

    **Cannot find fcitx im module for gtk 2.**

gtk 3:

    **Cannot find `gtk-query-immodules` for gtk 3**

    **Cannot find fcitx im module for gtk 3.**
```